# Nodejs Subselect in sql select

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

Ola!

I'm doing a node.js application. I have this table structure in my MySql DB:

[image]

My task is to get the *table_4 names* and the related *table_7 names*. I know the Table_1 username and password. Is it possible to create one query - using subselect - not calling all the time callback with a new select after getting values?  - like below -

```
con.connect(function(err) {  
    if (err) 
    {throw err }  
    con.query("SELECT id FROM Table_1 WHERE username = xyz AND password = aaa", 
        function (err, result) {
           if (err) {throw err};
           con.query("SELECT table_3_id FROM table2 WHERE Table_1_id = "+(result)+")", 
                  function(/*bla-bla*/){

                  };   
                }); 
    }
);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just talked to my lead dev, hwho gave me a correct solution - similar to @Vivek Doshi answer - :

```
SELECT  Table_4.names, Table_7.names
FROM    Table_1 , Table_2 , Table_3 , Table_4, Table_5, Table_6, Table_7
WHERE   Table_1.username and Table_1.password and 
        Table_2.Table_1_id = Table_1.id and 
        Table_2.Table_3_id = Table_3.id and
        Table_3.Table_4_id = table_4.id and
        Table_3.table_5_id = table_5.id and
        table_6.table_5_id = Table_5.id and
        table_6.table_7_id = table_7.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here it is how you can achieve that with one query :

```
SELECT  Table_4.*
FROM    Table_1 , Table_2 , Table_3 , Table_4
WHERE   Table_1.username and Table_1.password and 
        Table_2.Table_1_id = Table_1.id and 
        Table_2.Table_3_id = Table_3.id and
        Table_3.Table_4_id = Table_4.id
```

I couldn't found proper relations for Table_7 names. But I think you will get idea how to do it further from this.

Comment: thanks your reply, but I need table_4.name data and related table_7.name values.